# What path to use in Java for YAML arrays with multiple objects?

Tags: java, arrays, yaml, bukkit

I am currently trying to figure out how to get a String from my config.yml into my Java code. More specifically, which path to use to get *"Home"*, *"X:-1 Y:79 Z:3"*, *"Nether"* or *"X:23 Y:65 Z:-19"* extracted into my Java code. I already tried `getConfig().getString("Streuzel[0].name")`, but that didn't work.

YAML: (Array with multiple objects)

```yaml
Streuzel:
    -
        name: Home
        coords: X:-1 Y:79 Z:3
    -
        name: Nether
        coords: X:23 Y:65 Z:-19
```

Java:

```java
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + getConfig().getString("path?") + ChatColor.WHITE + ", " + ChatColor.GREEN + getConfig().getString("path?"));
```

Comment: What is with this trend of writing "Java" in all caps? Is some school teaching students that Java is an acronym?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `Streuzel` is a `List`, not an array, so you need to use `getList(String)` instead of `getString(String)`. In your case, each element of this list is a `Map<String, String>`. So, if you don't care about type cast safety (because yaml can be edited by humans and it potentially can lose structure), you can use something like this:

```java
((Map<String, String>)config.getList("Streuzel").get(0)).get("name") // Home
```

But ideally, you could either check if "Streuzel" is a list and if it contains a Map, or try...catch ClassCastException.

<s>About an answer that got posted 3 minutes ago: `Streuzel` is a `List`, not a `Map`!</s>
EDIT: they fixed it

Comment: @Elikill58 you said that `getConfig().getList("Streuzel")` will return a map, whereas it actually returns a list as stated in the function name

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get as list, you can use `getConfig().getList("Streuzel")` that will return a list of `LinkedHashMap<>`. You can use it like that:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> myObj = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) getConfig().getList("Streuzel").get(0);
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + myObj.get("name") + ChatColor.WHITE + ", " + ChatColor.GREEN + myObj.get("coords"));
```

But, this is not recommended. It's better to use configuration section like that:

```yaml
Streuzel:
    1:
        name: Home
        coords: X:-1 Y:79 Z:3
    2:
        name: Nether
        coords: X:23 Y:65 Z:-19
```

Then, you can use them like that:

```java
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + getConfig().getString("Streuzel.1.name") + ChatColor.WHITE + ", " + ChatColor.GREEN + getConfig().getString("Streuzel.1.coords"));
```

This way, with section, make it so much easier to get all content. If you want to find all sections, do like that:

```java
// here is the config with all keys
ConfigurationSection globalSection = getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Streuzel");
for(String keys : globalSection.getKeys(false)) { // all kays: "1", "2" ...
   ConfigurationSection objSection = globalSection.getConfigurationSection(keys);
   // here you can load your object, log it or get content with objSection.getString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can get a list of Map<String, Object> by using like so:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) getConfig().getList("Streuzel");
```

Though this works just fine, I personally am not a fan of it and wish it would support something like:

```java
List<ConfigurationSection> sections = getConfig().getSectionList("Streuzel");
```

But as far as I know, neither the Bukkit API nor API's based off of it (like Simple-YAML), support this.

[I have made an API that does support getting a list of sections](https://github.com/dieterblancke/ConfigurationAPI), feel free to check it out (it also supports both JSON and Yaml).